# What's the best way automate sorting files into folders based on a dictionary correspondence between the file name and folder?

Tags: filesystems, file-transfer, shell-script, file-permissions

I periodically receive a folder full of jumbled files that looks something like this:

> [Alice A] Messages 2020-01-03.zip
> [Bob B] Messages 2020-01-05.zip
> [Carl C] Messages 2020-01-08.zip
> [Alice A] Messages 2020-02-02.zip
> [Robert B] Messages 2020-02-07.zip

Etc. And I'd like to move them into folders in a specific directory:

> F:\Message Log\Alice Alexopoulos
> F:\Message Log\Robert Bakirtzis
> F:\Message Log\Carl Calimeris

I think I need the sorting to be based on a dictionary of some sort, because I need, for example, files labeled "Bob B" and "Robert B" to go into the same folder. I've looked at some other questions and it seems like they all assume that the files are going to a folder which is identical to part of the file name, so I think this question is worth a new post.

Comment: Depending on how many different folders and user names are used, it might be feasible to make a  *l o n g* IF statement in a batch script, with one IF for each possible user name... and on falling through with *no* match, move to a MISC folder.

Comment: Judging from the paths I suppose you use windows? Would a linux bash script also work for you?